# How to get stats through API about an email sent with Mandrill?

Tags: email, mandrill

I can't find a way to get all stats related to one email sent through Mandrill app? Do you use Mandrill api to get the stats?

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the documentation.  You can get stats for [a user](http://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/users.html#method=info), but not for an individual email.  It's unclear to me how an individual email would have statistical information anyway.  Have you tried contacting Mandrill directly?  We don't provide direct support for third-party products.

Comment: I've contacted them. It's transactional email, one-to-one so it make sense to get stats about each email like opens, clicks, forwards etc

Answer (score 9):

I think at this time 1+ years later it is now possible to query based on individual messages via Mandrill "Messages Calls" e.g. at https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method-info

**JSON Request**

```
{
"key": "example key",
"id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123"
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
"ts": 1365190000,
"_id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123",
"sender": "sender@example.com",
"template": "example-template",
"subject": "example subject",
"email": "recipient.email@example.com",
"tags": [
    "password-reset"
],
"opens": 42,
"opens_detail": [
    {
        "ts": 1365190001,
        "ip": "55.55.55.55",
        "location": "Georgia, US",
        "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
    }
],
"clicks": 42,
"clicks_detail": [
    {
        "ts": 1365190001,
        "url": "http://www.example.com",
        "ip": "55.55.55.55",
        "location": "Georgia, US",
        "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
    }
],
"state": "sent",
"metadata": {
    "user_id": "123",
    "website": "www.example.com"
},
"smtp_events": [
    {
        "ts": 1365190001,
        "type": "sent",
        "diag": "250 OK"
    }
]
}
```

hth somebody :)...